# How to disable Fn key on Acer Aspire (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: keyboard, function-keys

It seems like my Fn key is toggled on by default and I can't turn it off. For example, I can't press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window; I have to press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. This is annoying.

I've tried to turn it off by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, as I read elsewhere that that worked for people, but it didn't work for me. Also I gave a cursory glance at the BIOS but didn't see anything obviously relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Acer handles the way Fn key function in the Bios, what is your bios version, if you never updated your bios than most likely you running version 1.0 or 1.01 if you are update your bios and check again to see if the options are there.

Comment: It looks like I'd either have to install Windows (which I don't have) or "flash" the BIOS (which looks dangerous) to update it.  My BIOS is v1.05.

Comment: Maybe there's some kind of software workaround?

Comment: There is something you can try which is xmodmap, i have not used it personally but the description on on ubuntu site sounds promising http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xmodmap.1.html